# IP Addresses of inbound connections in bitcoin full node (TOR) looking as a localhost (127.0.0.1)

Tags: bitcoin-core, full-node, tor

I run bitcoin full node (mynode) through TOR and I see that inbound connections appear only as a localhost with varying ports usually in high range (examples `127.0.0.1:35010`, `127.0.0.1:58188`, `127.0.0.1:38804`, `127.0.0.1:56338`).

My config setup for TOR in bitcoin node is:

```
proxy=127.0.0.1:9050 
listen=1
bind=127.0.0.1
onlynet=onion
dnsseed=0
dns=0
```

What are these inbound connections? Are they nodes of other people or some apps running on my mynode? And if they are nodes of others why are they channeled through my home address and how?

Comment: Yeah, it's "some apps running on my mynode" ==> it's the Tor proxy :p

Answer (score 1):

Those are incoming connections coming through the proxy, which have no other possible identifier than coming from localhost (where the proxy daemon is running). The "sending" port number is effectively irrelevant for this situation. If you don't want incoming connections through the proxy, don't configure them to be allowed.